# A rather non-$F_\sigma$ Borel set

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets

I obtained a negative answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3821820/cardinality-of-the-collection-of-measurable-subsets-of-metric-outer-measures) question provided each metric space $X$ such that $|X|=\frak c$ and density $d(X)<\frak c$, contains a Borel set $B$ such that $|B\setminus C|=\frak c$ for each $F_\sigma$-subset $C$ of $X$ with $C\subset B$. My question is whether the latter claim holds. I guess this is  known (and true), but it is hard to find a reference. Thanks.

*My try.* I guess using [Theorem 22.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WM6LF.png) from [Kech] I can show the claim when $X$ is Polish. To prove the claim for a separable $X$, by [Proposition 12.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCkUk.png) from [Kech], it suffices to prove it for subspaces of an arbitrary fixed Polish space.

*References*

[Kech] A. Kechris, *Classical Descriptive Set Theory*, Springer, 1995.

Comment: [Cross-posted](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372191/a-rather-non-f-sigma-borel-set) and [answered](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/372191/a-rather-non-f-sigma-borel-set/372209#372209) by Paul Larson at MO.